# Elasticsearch: order posts by numder of friends liked

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm working on a social network project and stuck with this particular task.

When I do text search for posts, I need to first show the ones that the user's friends liked. I considered a few ways to deal with it:

1. Store the likes as an array of user ids and pass the user's friends list as a query parameter.
2. Store the likes as `nested` objects with user id and list of friends in it.
3. Denormalize the data even further, replace `posts` index with `likes` index and store the post text in each `like` document.
4. Combine #2 and #3, so, each `like` document contains the list of friends.

All of them look fine with small number of likes and friends, but, if we scale up to potential millions of likes and thousands of friends, they all have issues:

1. I don't want to send thousands of user ids as a query parameter for every single search request.
2. It would be a huge pain to keep the data consistent, I'd have to update all the posts liked by the user when they friend/unfriend somebody.
3. I'd have to store the same post text millions of times, and update millions of `likes` in case of an edit.
4. #2 and #3 combined.

Is there a better way to solve this kind of problems with Elasticsearch?

Or, maybe, there's a better tool for the job? For now, I decided to use ES for the text-search capabilities.

Comment: Do you need have a user ids? why you dont create a new field "like_by_friends" (amount like by friends) and use this field in function score for example applying weight for post with more likes?

Comment: @rabbitbr Thanks for the comment! 1. this search request may be triggered by any user, so, I'd have to store "like_by_{user_id}_friends". 2. I need to know which particular friend liked the post, so I can fetch their name and avatar and show them on UI later.